# Swift How to stop views from being called based on which Firebase user account is signed in

Tags: swift, firebase

In my app I have three different types of accounts (Customer, Employee, Business) and am doing Firebase call checks to see which user is currently signed-in and displaying the view that matches the current user. Problem is the code is executing for Employee/Business views that does not match the current users UID thus causing a crash. How can I stop this code from executing when the user UID does not match those profiles? I had put PRINT statements for the views so in the picture of the console you can see "Employee View" is being called before "Customer View" since a customer is signed-in the UID does not match the Firebase calls in "Employee View" thus a crash.

```
class Add: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var customerAdd: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var employeeAdd: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var businessAdd: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    print(uid)
    
    self.customerAdd.isHidden = true
    self.employeeAdd.isHidden = true
    self.businessAdd.isHidden = true
    
    print(datapass)
    print("Printing datapass here")
    
    checkIfCustomerIsSignedIn()
}

func checkIfCustomerIsSignedIn() {
    print("Called 1")
     Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        print("Called 2")
         if (user != nil) {
            print("Called 3")
             Database.database().reference().child("user_profiles").child((user?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                 if snapshot.exists() {
                    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
                    self.customerViewData = true
                    self.employeeViewData = false
                    self.businessViewData = false
                    
                    self.customerAdd.isHidden = false
                    self.employeeAdd.isHidden = true
                    self.businessAdd.isHidden = true
                 } else {
                     print("customer is not signed in")
                     //self.checkIfEmployeeIsSignedIn()
                 }
             })
         }
     })
 }

 func checkIfEmployeeIsSignedIn() {
     Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
         if (user != nil) {
             Database.database().reference().child("employees").child((user?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                 if snapshot.exists() {
                     print("employee is Signed In")
                     print("employee ADD")
                    self.customerViewData = false
                    self.employeeViewData = true
                    self.businessViewData = false
                    
                    self.customerAdd.isHidden = true
                    self.employeeAdd.isHidden = true
                    self.businessAdd.isHidden = true
                 } else {
                     print("employee is not singed in")
                     self.checkIfBusinessIsSignedIn()
                 }
             })
         }
     })
 }
 
 func checkIfBusinessIsSignedIn() {
     Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
         if (user != nil) {
             Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").child((user?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                 if snapshot.exists() {
                     print("Business is Signed In")
                     print("Business ADD")
                    self.customerViewData = false
                    self.employeeViewData = false
                    self.businessViewData = true
                    
                    self.customerAdd.isHidden = true
                    self.employeeAdd.isHidden = true
                    self.businessAdd.isHidden = false
                 } else {
                     print("No account is logged in so show anonymous")
                     self.customerViewData = true
                     self.employeeViewData = false
                     self.businessViewData = false
                    
                     self.customerAdd.isHidden = false
                     self.employeeAdd.isHidden = true
                     self.businessAdd.isHidden = true
                 }
             })
         }
     })
 }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try post a bit more code. For example, where are `customerViewData`, `employeeViewData` and `busineesViewData`. Where is datapass coming from? There are not enough information.

Anyway, I really recommend you changing the way you display data based on user type.
I think the most logical way to do this is to have three different views, each view with its VC and a parent view controller, which checks the user privilege and decides which view to display. This also more memory efficient compared to having 3 (3!) view displayed in the same screen when only one is being used.

Comment: customerViewData and etc. doesn't matter it's nil right now because I was testing on passing settings data. and I will post a picture of how my storyboard is set up

Comment: I had just added the storyboard picture of how my views are setup

Comment: Okay, thank you. You are looking at how to set up three custom child Viewcontroller. Check you implemented the `didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?)` method in your child VC. I suggest you have a look at this tutorial by Apple.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I will take a look

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion yet does not solve my problem